# Al iniciar sesión no se redirige a la página

Tags: php, base-de-datos, formularios

Tengo un formulario de inicio de sesión, que al introducir los datos (ya tengo usuarios creados y se conecta bien con la base de datos), no me hace nada, no me da error pero tampoco se redirige a la pagina del usuario.

```
<form class="caja-datos" method="post" action="">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="USUARIO">
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="CONTRASEÑA">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="iniciarsesion" value="Enviar">
  </form>


<?php

include("conexion.php");
   session_start();


   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['usuario']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['password']);

      $_SESSION['usuario']=$myusername;
      $_SESSION['password']=$mypassword;


      $sql = "SELECT usuario,password FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);


      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      header("location: usuario.php");

   }
?>
```

Comment: Podrias indicar la estructura de la carpeta donde esta usuario.php? Otra cosa muy tonta, pero que podria serlo, `header("Location: usuario.php");`, pon location con L mayuscula.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")` por  `if($_POST)`

Ya que `$ _SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD']` contiene el método de solicitud y `$ _POST` contiene cualquier dato de publicación.

Comment: por que? por favor añade una explicación a tu respuesta